# How to exclude folder from indexing but not from git? (IntelliJ IDEA, WebStorm)

Tags: git, intellij-idea, indexing, version-control, webstorm

I have the case, that I need to **exclude a folder** in WebStorm from indexing **but not from staging to git.** It is a folder `/dist/` with built files of the project which means i have duplicated lines of code.

Avoiding indexing on that folder means I have to remember every time I run the build and commit it to add the files manually. As I have a GitHub action that deploys the code to FTP on commit, the run fails because I have to delete all files prior to upload as Parcel (bundler) gives them random names on build.

How would I deal with that?

I haven't found a similar question, excluding the folder is the only way so far.

**EDIT:**
this is what marking as excluded looks like(red means not staged, although silently add created files + external files are activated)
[Image of directories](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uhGN6.png)

Answer (score 3):

**File** -> **Settings** -> **Directories** -> Use **Exclude** button

[image]

Comment: I will look again into it but that excludes it from git as far as i can see..

Comment: @Kekoa I checked it, and git doesn't exclude my changes in the excluded folder.

Comment: Unfortunately this works only for old files, as soon as I run my build and have new files in the folder, they are marked as ignored for VCS and there are no further settings. Adding the folder itself doesnt work aswell as it is unstaged as usually if the folder is empty

Comment: But i might get to the settings where every new file automatically stages, not 100% sure if I checked it on setup of webstorm but I believe I did

Comment: So i guess it must be a bug after setup, I still need to remember to add the files of the built folder to make the deployment run correctly with the newest built